# Google BigQuery SQL create multiple "columns" depending on if/then statement?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is this possible to do in a single query?

I have a sales table that I want to query. The table has details of our sales transactions at the item level, so each record contains fields like: **cust_no**, **item_no**, **amount**, **month**, **year**.

I want to summarize the sales info by customer by month by year. I know I can summarize the data like this:

```
select cust_no,
fiscal_year,
month,
sum(amount) as totalAmt,
group by cust_no, month, fiscal_year
```

...to get something like this:

| cust_no | month | fiscal year | totalAmt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cust_123 | 1 | 2022 | 123.45 |
| cust_345 | 1 | 2022 | 456.78 |

But I'd like to split out the sales amount depending on whether or not the item_no field is empty or not (because "products" have an item_no where as "services" have a blank item_no).

This is the result I'm going for:

| cust_no | month | fiscal year | totalAmt where item_no != '' | totalAmt where item_no = '' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cust_123 | 1 | 2022 | 123.45 | 222.22 |
| cust_345 | 1 | 2022 | 456.78 | 111.11 |

Is there a way to do this in a single query?

Comment: Can you update your sample and expected data to include `item_no`? Just to properly visualize your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try following query.

```sql
select 
    cust_no,
    fiscal_year,
    month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_no is NOT NULL THEN totalAmt ELSE 0 END) as total_amt_when_non_null,
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_no is NULL THEN totalAmt ELSE 0 END) as total_amt_when_null
FROM table
group by cust_no, month, fiscal_year
```

Comment: It should be "amount" instead of "totalAmt" and I had to change "is NULL" to = '' for it to work but it works great!